# Local mySql DB for testing on Android?

Tags: android, mysql, database, export, local

I want to use mySql Database from my site to create an android app, what is the best way to do this?

I think to use my database local on my computer and after i finished to programing the app, connect to the real database.

how to export the real database? with phpMyAdmin? or another way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work import your current DB directly I don't think that it's a good idea. Android works only with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database. Moreover you should implement [Android specific logic](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) to make it work in your app.

The best choice I think, it's access your data via HTTP from REST service on your site where you can easily communicate with MySql db.

Comment: But i don't want to do my tests on the real server, i want to try this before, there's any way to do this?

Comment: maybe you have some test environment for site? Or I'd like to test in on localhost